# WHCMS Order cancel or order remove

Tags: wordpress

[WHCMS Cancel Order API](https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/cancelorder/) says it accepts order ID and cancel it along with all items in that order. Does anyone confirm if an order is cancelled is it deleted by WHCMS from the system? There is a delete order API call as well which states that it deletes the order and this action can't be undone but I am asking does cancel order deletes the order as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the following and yes delete ORDER delete it from system as per the api docs

1. https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/domainrelease/
2. https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/deleteorder/
3. https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/deleteclient/
4. https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/closeclient/